# PHP - Manage Checkboxes in loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, for-loop, foreach

So, I have a variable which have all the menu_ids.
So what I want to show is - Check with the current variable i.e $get_all_menu_values and if the value is there, then mark it tick(checked).
Else leave it blank.

```
   <?php    
    $get_all_menu_values = "1,2,3,4,5"; ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($getSubMenuValues as $sub_menu): ?>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='<?=$sub_menu['menu_url']; ?>'><span><?=$sub_menu['menu_name']; ?></span></a></li>
    <div align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="form" value="" name="get_menu_values[]" /></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>   
    </ul>
```

In other words - check with the $get_all_menu_values and if the m_id is the same make it checked. More or less checking with IN array I guess.
But don't know how to do that.
Any help.

Thanks,
Kimz

Comment: Is `$get_all_menu_values` an array or string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [*in_array*](https://www.php.net/in_array) is what you need,

```
<?php
 $get_all_menu_values_array = explode(",",$get_all_menu_values); 
 foreach ($getSubMenuValues as $sub_menu):
   $isChecked = '';
   if(in_array($sub_menu['m_id'],$get_all_menu_values_array) {
      $isChecked = "checked='checked'";
   } 
?>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='<?=$sub_menu['menu_url']; ?>'><span><?=$sub_menu['menu_name']; ?></span></a></li>
<div align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="form" value="" name="get_menu_values[]" <?=$isChecked; ?> /></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in_array to check values

```
    $get_all_menu_values = "1,2,3,4,5";
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($getSubMenuValues as $sub_menu){ ?>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='<?=$sub_menu['menu_url']; ?>'><span><?=$sub_menu['menu_name']; ?></span></a></li>
    <div align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="form" value="" <?php (in_array($sub_menu["m_id"], $get_all_menu_values) ? "checked='checked'" : ""; ?> name="get_menu_values[]" /></div>
    <?php } ?>   
    </ul>
```